# How to safely switch to python3 as default after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, python, python3

Since `python3` is the default python version in Ubuntu 18.04 and `python2` won't be shipped by default on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation, how can I make `python3` default after an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 (from 16.04). Currently, after the upgrade to `python2` it still defaulted (e.g. `python` command directs to `python2` etc.).  However, purging the `python` package will result in removing too many packages that rely on it, so this is not an option here.

Ideally, I want to remove the `python2` dependency as much possible. Maybe the upgrade process could be designed in such a way that it checks all packages, whether they still really rely on `python2` dependencies and thereby collect all `python2` dependencies that could be replaced by an equivalent `python3` dependency (which will be resolved by the upgrade then).

Comment: Please check the new wording.  Previous was somewhat unclear on what you were asking.  Tried to sort this out from the title of your post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the edit @JuanAntonio. They majority of the edits look good. Just did some further corrections to get this questions into right direction.

Comment: Is this safe, what is the end of removing python2 or leaving it. If it's there then something needs it!

Comment: In fact python 2 is not installed by default in 18.04, so if you have it, it is because you installed some additional package (or did an upgrade with said packages already installed), which still requires python 2. That 3.x is _default_ does not mean there are no more things using 2.x in the archive. 20.04 will surely not have python 2.x any more though, as it will no longer be supported by upstream at that point.

Comment: "what is the end of removing python2" - a rather clean system. my python installations where somehow broken after the upgrade.

Comment: "so if you have it, it is because you installed some additional package (or did an upgrade with said packages already installed), which still requires python 2" <- yes, but after a risky cleanup (i.e. actually I did the risky purge step), my systems generally runs now without `python2`dependencies - even parts that rely on the "deprecated" `python2`dependency after upgrade, i.e., all those parts are obviously replaced by "equivalent" `python3`dependencies now. it looks like that only a few packages that I've installed before really rely on the `python2` dependency.

Answer (score 39):

This post is a bit old, but I believe a better alternative exists: enter `update-alternatives`. The following will set your `/usr/bin/python` to default to 2.7 but have 3.6 available when you want:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7 20
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.6 10
```

The highest priority here is used as the "automatic" choice for `/usr/bin/python` but you can easily switch by running `sudo update-alternatives --config python`.

Comment: nice answer. in my case, python2.7 was being installed by nodejs/npm and somehow set as default for `python`. I used `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all python` to remove all python, and then added the only python I want to use `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 10`. Also good to know is `sudo update-alternatives --list python` to see what is what.

Comment: you may also want to do `sudo apt install python3-pip` and `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 10`

Comment: i still get 2 after doing this.

Answer (score 18):

To completely remove python2, you have to purge the `python2.x-minimal` package which is done by

```
sudo apt purge python2.x-minimal
```

replacing x with the exact version of python 2 on your system. But make sure to look at what other packages are removed as you may have carried packages that still depend on python 2 even after the upgrade, and those packages will be uninstalled as well and cease to work.

---

There isn't such a thing as a 'default' python interpreter because it just depends on which actual file `/usr/bin/python` points to, to change this to python use the `ln` command to update the link, for instance let's say you want it to point to python 3.6

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Alternatively, if you just want this for your user, you can set it as your alias in your `.bashrc`, to do that, open `~/.bashrc` in your editor of choice and add the following line

```
alias python='python3.6'
```

Comment: "as you may have carried packages that still depend on python 2 even after the upgrade" <- yes, and my intention is to get rid of this dependency as it is not really necessary, since Ubuntu 18.04 runs them without `python2`dependency by using its default `python3` dependencies/packages.

Comment: Is this safe, what is the end of removing python2 or leaving it. If it's there then something needs it!

Answer (score 1):

On my 16.04 `/usr/bin/python` is just a link to `/usr/bin/python2.7` so I assume you would just have to change this link to point to `/usr/bin/python3.x` (with adequate `x` of course).

Comment: you could also point `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`, which is a link to the latest python3 version installed. Or just an alias or a function in your `~/.bashrc`. Tons of options ;-)

Comment: no, I guess, that this is not really what I want to do here. I want to get rid of `python2` in my system (as it is the default case when installing a fresh ubuntu 18.04, where `python3` is default and `python2` is not installed per default)

Comment: @zazi I would not recommend purging `python2`. It seems that many other packages are depending on it. Do you have any disadvantages by keeping `python2` installed?

Comment: I have no disadvantage keeping `python2` installed, if really necessary, but I want to clearly set `python3` as default, i.e., remove the `python2` as often as possible (and a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04 demonstrates that this is possible).

Comment: Indeed it does.

Comment: This is bad advice. You should never make `/usr/bin/python` point to python3. It is advised against by upstream Python.

Comment: Yes, but that was before 18.04. In addition there is no other python on the system... In fact giving a python2 script to python3 usually makes it croak even before running it (you need a single `print` statement...) somewhere in the code. The real problem is wanting to completely get rid on python2. There are still packages that depend on it (Gimp, for instance).

Comment: @xenoid: yes, Gimp is one of those examples that still really rely on `python2`, but there are many that do not really need anymore this "deprecated" `python2`dependency, but still have it after the upgrade and that's what's bugs me somehow atm.